# Can NetMsmqBinding be used with multicast?

Tags: wcf, msmq, netmsmqbinding, msmqintegrationbinding

I'm trying to put together a multicast MSMQ example.  All the examples I find for multicast using PGM have the integration binding.  I'd rather not have to modify all my contracts to use MsmqMessage, and I'm concerned I won't be able to attach security to the messages.  Is there something I'm overlooking, or did I paint myself into a corner?

Comment: What's PGM as a matter of interest?

Comment: Pragmatic Multicasting.  The term is not really important, I just want to use NetMsmqBinding to do multicasting if I can.

Answer (score 0):

You may open multiple instance from your handler at one time, each will work on a different message from the queue simultaneously.

Comment: You do know that multicast means different handlers receiving the *same* message, right?